# How to filter out the antibody light chains into kappa and lambda types on the PDB website?

Tags: antibody, pdb

The antibody light chains can either be kappa or lambda types. I am searching homologous sequences on the [RCSB PDB website](https://www.rcsb.org/). Is there a way to filter out these two types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The instructions are as follows.

1. Go to the [RCSB PDB Webite](https://www.rcsb.org/).
2. Under the search bar, click `Browse by Annotations`.
3. Click the blue tab labeled `SCOP`.
4. Click the white arrow next to the folder titled **`All Beta Protiens`**.
5. Click the white arrow next to the folder titled **`Immunoglobulin-like beta-sandwich (...)`**.
6. Click the white arrow next to the folder titled **`Immunoglobulins (Superfamily)`**.

This is where it splits, based on your specific search.

**For Light Chain, Constant Domain:**

1. Click the white arrow next to the folder titled **`C1 set domains (antibody constant domain-like)`**.
2. For Kappa Type, Click the folder (not the arrow) titled **`Immunoglobulin light chain kappa constant domain, CL-kappa`**.
3. For Lambda Type, Click the folder (not the arrow) titled **`Immunoglobulin light chain lambda constant domain, CL-lambda`**.

**For Light Chain, Variable Domain:**

1. Click the white arrow next to the folder titled **`V set domains (antibody variable domain-like)`**.
2. For Kappa Type, Click the folder (not the arrow) titled **`Immunoglobulin light chain kappa variable domain, VL-kappa (...)`**.
3. For Lambda Type, Click the folder (not the arrow) titled **`Immunoglobulin light chain lambda variable domain, VL-lambda (...)`**.

This should get you to the list of proteins that you are looking for.

Comment: Very very helpful! Just to confirm, would it be possible that some antibody PDB are not fully annotated so not included in this search?

Comment: Yes, a lot of them are not included in the above searches. However, you can find most of the rest here -> https://www.rcsb.org/pdb/search/smartSubquery.do?smartSearchSubtype=TreeQuery&t=12&n=1933

Comment: @lanselibai Would you like me to add instructions for heavy chain types as well?

Comment: Of course, go for it!